# Is there a way to join 2 dataframes using another reference table in python

Tags: python

I have 2 data frames created from CSV files and there is another data frame which is a reference for these table. For e.g.

1 Employee demographic (Emp_id, dept_id)

2 Employee detail (Emp_id, RM_ID)

I have 3rd dataframe(dept_manager) which has only 2 columns (dept_id, RM_ID). Now I need to join table 1 and 2 referencing the 3rd dataframe.

Trying out in pandas(python) any help here would be much appreciated..Thanks in advance.

```
Table1
Empdemogr

      Empid    dept_id
       1           10
       2           20
       1           30

Table2
Empdetail

        Empid     RM_id
         1          E120
         2          E140
         3          E130


Table3
dept_manager

      dept_id    RM_id
      10          E110
      10          E120
      10          E121
      10          E122
      10          E123
      20          E140
      20          E141
      20          E142
      30          E130
      30          E131
      30          E132

Output:

       Emp_id   dept_id RM_id
        1          10     E120
        2          20     E140
        1          30     E130

So trying to bring this sql in python:

select a.Emp_id, a.dept_id, b.RM_id
Empdemogr a, Empdetail b, dept_manager d
where 
a.emp_id=b.emp_id
and a.dept_id=d.dept_id
and b.RM_id=d.RM_id
```

Comment: Could you add sample input and sample output data?

Comment: @san added a sample input and output.

Comment: Trying to figure out if you had a typo or you have wrong understanding. Your above SQL would not output the the result you are looking for based on the provided data. I do not think you will see dept_id '30' in there.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to figure out if you had a typo or you have wrong understanding. Your above SQL would not output the the result you are looking for based on the provided data. I do not think you will see dept_id '30' in there.

But Going by your SQL query, here is how you can write the same in python dataframe:

**Preparing DataFrames (I will leave it up to you how you load the dataframes):**

```
import pandas as pd

EmpployeeDemo=pd.read_csv(r"YourEmployeeDemoFile.txt")
EmpDetail=pd.read_csv(r"YourEmpDetailFile.txt")
Dept_Manager=pd.read_csv(r"YourDept_Manager.txt")
```

**Code to Join the DataFrames:**

```
joined_dataframe = pd.merge(pd.merge(EmpployeeDemo, EmpDetail, on="Empid"),Dept_Manager, on=["dept_id", "RM_id"])
print(joined_dataframe)
```

Comment: @ABC Did this help?